# Show independence without using Basu theorem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, independence, sampling

$X_1,...,X_n,i.i.d,X_1\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

prove that $\xi=f(X_1,...,X_n)$ and $\bar X$ are independent, where $f(X_1,...,X_n)=f(X_1+c,...,X_n+c)$  for any constant $c$

I know this can be done by using Basu theorem, and the book says an orthogonal transform will work too, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have $f(X_1,\dots,X_n) = f(X_1 - \bar{X},\dots,X_n - \bar{X})$, where of course, $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i .$ So it is sufficient to show that $\bar{X}$ and $X_1 - \bar{X},\dots,X_n - \bar{X}$ are independent.

From joint normality and the fact that $\text{Cov}(\bar{X},X_i - \bar{X}) = 0$  for $1 \leq i \leq n$ it follows that $\bar{X}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n l_i (X_i - \bar{X})$ are independent (for any choice of $l_1,\dots, l_n$) and hence $\bar{X}$ and $X_1 - \bar{X},\dots,X_n - \bar{X}$ are independent.

Comment: Can we do minus $\bar X$ directly or do we need to state something? I was not sure it can be seen as a constant before.

Comment: $f$ is just a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x_1+c,x_2+c,\dots,x_n+c) = f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ for **all** $c \in \mathbb{R}$.